# How to install dig on Cygwin?

Tags: package-management, cygwin, dig

I cannot find `dig` command on my Cygwin, nor any package name that would directly point to it. If there is a package containing it, then which one to install?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To find the proper package that contains a specific file, you can always use `cygcheck -p` to ask the Cygwin server:

---

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/dig

Found 6 matches for bin/dig
bind-debuginfo-9.11.5-2.P4 - bind-debuginfo: Debug info for bind
bind-debuginfo-9.11.6-1 - bind-debuginfo: Debug info for bind
bind-debuginfo-9.11.9-1 - bind-debuginfo: Debug info for bind
bind-utils-9.11.5-2.P4 - bind-utils: DNS server and utilities suite
bind-utils-9.11.6-1 - bind-utils: DNS server and utilities suite
bind-utils-9.11.9-1 - bind-utils: DNS server and utilities suite
```

---

Additional information source: [`cygcheck` man page](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygcheck.html):

> **`-p`, `--package-query`  search for REGEXP in the entire [cygwin.com](https://cygwin.com/) package repository (requires internet connectivity)**

Answer (score 14):

The correct package name for Cygwin at least is: `bind-utils`:

[image: bind-utils package on Cygwin]

---

As you can see I've already installed it. Also to note, there was nothing to configure for `dig` to work right after installation.